# Ion range slider color and dragger not showing in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, npm, ion-range-slider

I am trying to add ion-rangeslider in my project

This is my HTML code

```
<div style="position: relative; padding: 200px;">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="range" value="" name="range" />
                </div>
</div>
```

This is my Jquery code

```
 $(function () {

            $("#range").ionRangeSlider({
                hide_min_max: true,
                keyboard: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 5000,
                from: 1000,
                to: 4000,
                type: 'double',
                step: 1,
                prefix: "$",
                grid: true
            });

        });
```

This is what I am getting on the screen.

[image]

As we can see the color inside the slider is not showing as well as the dragger for setting the values. 
I don't know why it is not showing. Can anyone help?
By the way, I am using Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Open Developer Tools and Inspect the element. Find the relevant elements/classes and adjust the colors using css.